# Diplomatic Status of a territory?

Tags: vocabulary

What would you call the status of a territory? The territory can be a country, a region, a state, what is the expression that qualifies its status, is it a `diplomatic status` ?

Comment: Too Broad. You could refer to a territory's ***political*** status, or its ***ecological*** status, for example.

Comment: You are looking for an overarching term, perhaps a hypernym meaning any kind of geopolitical organization?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit too vague to give a definitive answer. *[Territory](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/territory)* is defined variously as

> - An area of land; a region
> - The land and waters under the jurisdiction of a government
> - A political subdivision of a country
> - A geographic region, such as a colonial possession, that is dependent on an external government: the territories of the Holy Roman Empire
> - (often Territory)  A subdivision of the United States that is not a state and is administered by an appointed or elected governor and elected legislature
> - A similarly organized political subdivision of Canada or Australia
> - An area for which a person is responsible as a representative or agent: a salesperson's territory
> - Sports The area of a field defended by a specified team: punted the ball deep into the opponent's territory
> - Biology An area occupied by a single animal, mating pair, or group and often vigorously defended against intruders, especially those of the same species
> - A sphere of action or interest; a province

If you are looking for a political position about the status of *territory*, it will very much depend on which political organization you are inquiring about - the US? Canada? the UN? some other locale or jurisdiction?

Comment: I think you may have given the answer here. It's *political status,* isn't it?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Well, yes, but only if he is referring to the type of territory that *enjoys* a political status (many types are commercial, scientific, informal, etc.). Which type is not clear from his question. I guess I was trying to prompt OP to further define the issue.